# CX_ORACLE importing CSV with unwanted NULL

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I'm having issues with unwanted NULL's in the last rows of a CSV file. For example, a 2 column CSV file that holds 10 rows of correct data & 5 additional rows of what I assume is blank cells. See txt insert:-

```
a8,06/05/2020
a9,06/05/2020
a10,06/05/2020
,
,
,
,
,
```

I'm using CX_ORACLE to import the data into the Database but it's also importing the 5 blank rows with NULLs.

Any idea of how I can exclude blank CSV rows at the end of the file. Below is an extract of my import:-

```
# Initialize list that will serve as a container for bind values
L = []

UpdateLog ('Load CSV file into List...')
reader = csv.reader(open(map_drive + ':\\'+ sp_file), delimiter=',')

# the code exludes the column headers on row
UpdateLog ('Skip Header Row...')
next(reader)

for row in reader:
    L.append(tuple(row))

# prepare insert statement
UpdateLog ('Creating INSERT Statement')
cursor.prepare(insert)


# execute insert with executemany
cursor.executemany(None, L)

# report number of inserted rows
UpdateLog ('Inserted: ' + str(cursor.rowcount) + ' rows into ' + table)
tmpRowCount = cursor.rowcount

cursor = connection.cursor()

#commit
connection.commit()
UpdateLog ('End import to '+ table)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be better solutions, but this is how I got around the problem.

```
for row in reader:
    if any(row):                 # Pick up the non-blank row of list
        print (row)              # Just for verification
        user_list.append(row)    # Compose all the rest data into the list
```